# Learning go-ethereum For Custom Chain

Tags: go-ethereum, blockchain, private-blockchain

Is there a site to find out all about source code go-ethereum? I want to learn fully about the Ethereum blockchain.I want to learn private blockchain to learn more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

-it is about private blockchain https://geth.ethereum.org/docs/interface/private-network
-it is about geth developed https://geth.ethereum.org/docs/developers/devguide

It is all based on go-ethereum https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum. I recommend you clone official repo and followed official instructions for build using go and learn code.
Good luck!